# AirPrint and a NSMutableString

Tags: ios, nsmutablestring, airprint

I am a little stuck:-)

I have a small app which allows me to put in fields from the address book into a label type UIView. Now I wish to be able to print those labels out:-)
I do not mind at this stage if it goes onto a normal piece of paper - I will sort that part out later.

My Questions is - I cannot figure out how to print text that I draw out from the addressbook.

EXAMPLE:

First Name: -------- | This become | First Name: Joe Bloggs (from the address book)

[image]

Now the section that has the name, household, age and number - That is the section I want to print out.

Any Help?? Please???

PS I have start to code my way through this, so I am not giving this to you blank. I just got a fair bit of code:-) So I am not sure which bit to post.

The bit that causes the error is this:

```
NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",self.encoded.text, self.decoded.text];
```

Cheers
--Jeff

Comment: this one:

/Users/jwkranenburg/Desktop/1st design/Cue2Info/Cue2Info/printViewController.m:87:83: error: property 'encoded' not found on object of type 'printViewController *' [3]

Comment: Of what class are encoded & decoded?

Comment: self.encoded.text & self.decoded.text - hope it helps:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error : `property 'encoded' not found on object of type 'printViewController *'` seems to indicate that you have not declared encoded as a property. In order to use the dot notation you are using you will have to declare `encoded` and `decoded` as properties.

I'm going to assume that encoded is of class `UILabel`, since that is what it looks like in your screenshot. If my assumption about it's class is correct you need to declare it as a property like so.

In your `printViewController.h` file you should have:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *encoded;
```

And in your `.m` file you should have:

```
@synthesize encoded;
```

Or some manually written accessors.

You will need to connect the label itself to your IBOutlet on the view controller which you can do from interface builder.

If I have misunderstood your layout leave a comment.

Comment: Hey Thanks for this - it worked:-) Sorry for the late reply, had a hard night Thanks again:-)